# Capture image from camera and save it

Tags: vba, image, ms-access, save, capture

I want to add a button in my form (MS Access Database), so it can capture image from my camera (laptop) and save it in a specific location (c:\image).

I am using windows 10 with office 2010 or office 365.

Code with WIA:

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    
    Dim oWIA_DeviceManager As WIA.DeviceManager
    Dim oWIA_Device As WIA.Device
    Dim oWIA_ComDlg As WIA.CommonDialog
    Dim oImageFile As WIA.ImageFile
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set oWIA_DeviceManager = New WIA.DeviceManager
      
    If oWIA_DeviceManager.DeviceInfos.Count > 0 Then
        Set oWIA_ComDlg = New WIA.CommonDialog
          
        ' Index the Devices property starting here at 1, not 0 .
        For i = 1 To oWIA_DeviceManager.DeviceInfos.Count
            Set oWIA_Device = oWIA_DeviceManager.DeviceInfos.Item(i).Connect
          
            ' Use this to show Acquisition CommonDialog
            Set oImageFile = oWIA_ComDlg.ShowAcquireImage
              
            ' Use this to show Acquisition Wizard
            'Set oImageFile = oWIA_ComDlg.ShowAcquisitionWizard(oWIA_Device)
    
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "No WIA compatible device attached!"
    End If
      
End Sub
```

With this I open my iPhone camera (usb attach). I need to use my in-build camera of my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page is probably what you need.
http://www.developerfusion.com/thread/46191/how-to-capture-picture-using-webcam-in-vb60/

```
'******************* module code **************

Public Const WS_CHILD As Long = &H40000000
Public Const WS_VISIBLE As Long = &H10000000


Public Const WM_USER As Long = &H400
Public Const WM_CAP_START As Long = WM_USER


Public Const WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT As Long = WM_CAP_START + 10
Public Const WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT As Long = WM_CAP_START + 11
Public Const WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW As Long = WM_CAP_START + 50
Public Const WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE As Long = WM_CAP_START + 52
Public Const WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOFORMAT As Long = WM_CAP_START + 41
Public Const WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB As Long = WM_CAP_START + 25






Public Declare Function capCreateCaptureWindow _
    Lib "avicap32.dll" Alias "capCreateCaptureWindowA" _
         (ByVal lpszWindowName As String, ByVal dwStyle As Long _
        , ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long _
        , ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hwndParent As Long _
        , ByVal nID As Long) As Long






Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long _
        , ByVal wParam As Long, ByRef lParam As Any) As Long


'************* end of module code ******************

Add the following controls in a form

1. A picture box with name "PicWebCam"

2. A commondialog control with name "CDialog"

3. Add 4 command buttons with name "cmd1","cmd2,"cmd3","cmd4"

then paste the following code

'************************** Code **************

Dim hCap As Long
Private Sub cmd4_Click()
Dim sFileName As String
    Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, CLng(False), 0&)
    With CDialog
        .CancelError = True
        .Flags = cdlOFNPathMustExist Or cdlOFNOverwritePrompt
        .Filter = "Bitmap Picture(*.bmp)|*.bmp|JPEG Picture(*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files|*.*"
        .ShowSave
        sFileName = .FileName









    End With
    Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB, 0&, ByVal CStr(sFileName))
DoFinally:
    Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, CLng(True), 0&)
End Sub




Private Sub Cmd3_Click()
Dim temp As Long
temp = SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0&, 0&)
End Sub


Private Sub Cmd1_Click()
hCap = capCreateCaptureWindow("Take a Camera Shot", WS_CHILD Or WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, PicWebCam.Width, PicWebCam.Height, PicWebCam.hWnd, 0)
    If hCap <> 0 Then
        Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0)
        Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 66, 0&)
        Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, CLng(True), 0&)
    End If
End Sub






Private Sub Cmd2_Click()
Dim temp As Long
temp = SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOFORMAT, 0&, 0&)
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()
cmd1.Caption = "Start &Cam"
cmd2.Caption = "&Format Cam"
cmd3.Caption = "&Close Cam"
cmd4.Caption = "&Save Image"
End Sub
'**************** Code end ************************
```

Basically what this is doing is using the windows message pump to send messages to web cam driver, asking it to take a picture.
Also, a tip for future self help.  You can often get better results by searching VB6, which is almost the exact same thing as VBA. VBA just has a few less functions.

If you lack the common dialog control. You can change the code to this

```
Private Sub cmd4_Click()
Dim sFileName As String
    Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, CLng(False), 0&)
    sFileName="C:\PathToNewImageFile.bmp"
    Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_FILE_SAVEDIB, 0&, ByVal CStr(sFileName))
DoFinally:
    Call SendMessage(hCap, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, CLng(True), 0&)
End Sub
```

Comment: thxs for your reply. I am having problem with "2. A commondialog control with name "CDialog"". Where I can I find it in access 2007?

Comment: Click on your tools menu. Then Additional Controls.
Find "Microsoft Common Dialog" control. And check that off.
Then click ok, and a new item will appear in your tool box.  Draw that onto your userform to add it, then click on it at the bottom to bring up the properties and give it a name.
However, I tried doing this on my excel 2013, and was unable to, so yeah... fingers crossed, otherwise we have to use the windows API to do it.

It looks like it is only used to give you a save location.  You can hard code this as a test if you want.  Answer updated

Comment: Adjustment I had to do for Access db described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757965/how-to-use-webcam-capture-on-a-microsoft-access-form

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used WIA (Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition) for scanners but it will work with webcams. I'd definitely try it.

Comment: Do you think it will work with my laptop camera? Do you have any code to test? thxs in advance.